# Is the phrase ''Regarding my educational journey'' correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I want to use it in this sentence '  Regarding my educational journey, it is glaring that studying and doing research are endeavors I would like to engage in even more'

Comment: What is wrong in it?  You may even consider 'pursuit' in place of journey.  The usual ways is, ...pursue one's studies/ interests etc.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence is confusing. Unless, of course, you intend to convey that it is a great error on your part to undertake both the activities that you have mentioned in your quest to achieve, what you possibly perceive to be, excellence in education of a sort that is, not at the present point of time, impossible for me to imagine or speculate.

Comment: Obviously, my response has fallen foul of one who considers a specific adjective in the sentence not entirely out of place. It is merely a conjecture and I suffer from a condition that makes my digital skin akin to a pachyderm.